# Is there a way to search for old iCloud accounts?

Tags: macos, icloud, photos, apple-id, photos.app

My wife's old MacBook got destroyed and I have no idea if it was ever backed up or not.

Sometime before it got destroyed we bought iPhones and had to set up the Apple ID with our emails.  Our iPhone pics and videos are uploaded to iCloud but her old Mac pics and videos are not there.

Since we had to set up Apple IDs I'm assuming she didn't have one for her MacBook.  But I know for a fact that she used to buy songs from iTunes and download them to her MacBook, so I'm assuming she had some kind of Apple ID back then.  We just don't know what it was.

I would love to figure out a way to recover those old photos if possible. I assume finding the old iCloud account would allow us to log in and check what's there.

Can anyone suggest a way I might be able to achieve this?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best with your question.

Comment: https://iforgot.apple.com/appleid#!&section=appleid